# beginners query about asp.net website management

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I recently started managing a asp.net website. earlier my employee had simple HTML and one php website and I can easily work with both of them and can do medium level of customization like add/edit things. But now i have asp.net website and its killing me.

All the files are precompiled but I have source code. Please tell me how to add edit content etc. Consider me as a student with required knowledge of HTML, php and css.

For example I was told to add a table in a page, I had html code for same but did not know how to do it. I tried adding it in HTML file and aspx file but no use. Than I add it in files in bin folder and website started giving error about precompile index file first.

Now when you know my understanding about asp.net is nil, please, guide me to save myself from embarrassment I may face. Although its not my job M into marketing but during interview I said that I can do it all w/o knowing they have asp.net for me. Also let me know the tools I require like visual studio, iis etc.

Comment: Get yourself a (free) copy of Visual Web Developer 2010.  You can test your changes locally by running the code, then deploy it to your server using "Publish".  Good luck ...

Comment: @dbaseman thanks for reply. I am going to test it today evening itself. While serching I found that visual express is free but not web developer.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say the express version is free.  That version is fine for most development tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is why ASP.NET works best for complicated websites with a well-defined build/deploy process and not simple websites that need updating regularly.

You should be able to add and edit static content in the `*.master`, `*.aspx` and `*.ascx` files without any problems - the ASP.NET runtime will recompile those files on the server, so there is no need for the source files - unless the website was compiled with "stub" `*.aspx` files (that's when the files have a single line that looks like `<%@ Page Inherits="MyAssembly.SomePage" %>`).

You said you tried this already, but that it was of "no use". Can you explain what happened afterwards? Did you get any error messages?

The `bin` folder is where you put the DLL files from the project after it has been built (the build process includes compilation). Can you please show us the entire "precompile index file first" error message you received? The descriptions you've given us are too vague to help you with.

If your ASP.NET site does not have any custom logic beyond a simple "Contact Us" email form, then I strongly suggest you convert it back to a static HTML or PHP website, if only to save everyone's sanity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a question here, and there's not going to be a substitute for "cracking the book", watching some on-line tutorials, etc.  I appreciate you're in a tough spot, but just willy-nilly adding stuff to an .aspx file will cause you serious grief in the long run.

Do a Bing search for PHP an ASP.NET and you'll find some relevant resources that leverage skills you already do have to bring you into the ASP.NET mindset, explain the development and deployment model, and describe the page lifecycle model.

Here are a few:

[ASP.NET for PHP Developers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-for-php-developers/)

[Get Started with ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/get-started)

[ASP.NET for PHP Developers: Introduction to ASP.NET](https://www.microsoftelearning.com/eLearning/course.aspx?guid=C47815A5-B80D-4531-B358-9EEEA36316C1)